# conda activate fails but the shell prompt has changed

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

I am using `conda==4.6.2`.

When I do `conda activate xx`, the prompt of the shell has been changed to be prefixed with `(xx)`, but when I type `which python`, the `python` is still the python of the `base` environment.

The behaviour is not reproducible. It occurs sometimes but not always. But it is very annoying that sometimes something fails because the `conda` does not switch the environment.

Does anyone happen to suffer from it, either?

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Note: The problem actually occurs in `conda==4.5` too.

Comment: Did you specify a different Python interpreter when creating the virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out:

- To use `conda`, the path of `base` environment is in my `PATH`, like `export PATH="/miniconda/bin:$PATH"`
- I activated `conda`, which adds the path of `xx` environment to `PATH`, now `PATH` is `/miniconda/envs/xx/bin:/miniconda/bin`
- I do something like invoke a `zsh`, which again add the path of `base` environmen in my `PATH`, now `PATH` is `/miniconda/bin:/miniconda/envs/xx/bin:/miniconda/bin`
- I activated `conda`, which only modifies the prompt of `zsh`. So when I invoke `python`, it is the python of the `base` environment.

This is a change introduced in [conda==4.6.3](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell).

Comment: There was a change since Conda v4.4 that no longer recommends having the base env directory in `PATH`.  Please see [the relevant release notes](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell) for more details on the updated recommended practice.